# turtle graphics - spacing drawing shapes

Tags: python, drawing, distance, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

In the code below, how can I give some space after
drawing each shape and then draw the next shape.

```
from turtle import *

color('black','green')
shape('turtle')
pensize(5)
speed(1)

def makeShape (numSides):
    for i in range(numSides):
        forward(100)
        left(360.0/numSides)
        i += 1
        

for i in range(3,13):
    makeShape(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can change the code like this:

```
space = [10, 30, 50]
for i in range(3,6):
    makeShape(i)
    up()
    setpos(space[i-3], space[i-3])
    down()
```

The numbers are test and you can change the numbers for the distances according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `penup()` and `pendown()` functions, which stop and start the 'Drawing mode' respectively.

Then just move the pen forward in the direction needed!

A function might look something like this:

```py
def somespace(spaceamount):
    penup()
    forward(spaceamount)
    pendown()
```

then just call it with the rest of your code:

```py
--snip--
for i in range(3,13):
    makeShape(i)
    # orientate shape here if needed
    somespace(50) # give space of 50
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code the i am sharing will produce a dashed square that will make you better understand:

**important points**

1. penup() is method from Turtle class that you can access with an object that in my case i access it with **tim** abject, will take the pen up from the screen (Not Drawing)
2. pendown() is method from **Turtle** class that you can access with an object that in my case i access it with **tim** abject, will take the pen down on the screen (Drawing)

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tim = Turtle()
tim.shape("turtle")
tim.color('red')

turn = 0
while turn < 4:
    for _ in range(30):
        tim.forward(5)
        tim.penup()
        tim.forward(5)
        tim.pendown()
    turn += 1    
    tim.right(90)


screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```